# Why does my WPF application crash when I bump my mousewheel?

Tags: c#, wpf

When I bump my mousewheel, my WPF application crashes sometimes, with an OverflowException. Here's the start of the stack trace:

```
at System.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker._HandleNCHitTest(WM uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
```

From that, I've traced it down to the WindowChrome - I can even reproduce it with just the WindowChrome. But it seems like it has to be fullscreen. What's going on here? Is there a workaround?

Comment: There is a workaround for the problem here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167357/overflow-exception-in-windowchrome.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is actually an issue in the class the stack trace points to. Microsoft has a bug in the `WindowChromeWorker` that manifests in an `OverflowException`.

I've only observed this with Logitech mice, but from what I've seen elsewhere, it may happen with other mice.

The only workarounds available are disallowing full-screen, and preventing the user from sending a message containing side-scroll information.

What I think is going on is this:

```
//Overflow gets inlined to here. (In System.Windows.Shell.WindowChromeWorker.cs)
var mousePosScreen = new Point(Utility.GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), Utility.GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));

//Which calls this (In Standard.Utility)
public static int GET_X_LPARAM(IntPtr lParam)
{
    return LOWORD(lParam.ToInt32());
}

//Unsafe cast and overflow happens here (In System.IntPtr)
public unsafe int ToInt32() {
    #if WIN32
        return (int)m_value;
    #else
        long l = (long)m_value;
        return checked((int)l); //Overflow actually occurs and is thrown from here.
    #endif
}
```

It seems like a bad assumption is made in `Standard.Utility` that `lParam`s always fit in 32 bits, and some mouse drivers violate that on 64-bit systems by writing there.

The reference source for `WindowChromeWorker` is [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Shell/WindowChromeWorker.cs,369313199b0de06c).

Comment: Nice find! Thanks for posting!

Comment: There is a workaround for the problem here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/167357/overflow-exception-in-windowchrome.html

Answer (score 2):

The workaround that [Ivan Golović](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773514/ivan-golovi%c4%87) included in a comment above needs to be in an answer so it can be spotted easily and in case the link goes dead.

Preprocess the message in a HookProc and mark it as handled if the conversion from lParam to int32 overflows.

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized( EventArgs e )
  {
     base.OnSourceInitialized( e );
     ( (HwndSource)PresentationSource.FromVisual( this ) ).AddHook( HookProc );
  }
  private IntPtr HookProc( IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled )
  {
     if ( msg == 0x0084 /*WM_NCHITTEST*/ )
     {
        // This prevents a crash in WindowChromeWorker._HandleNCHitTest
        try
        {
           lParam.ToInt32();
        }
        catch ( OverflowException )
        {
           handled = true;
        }
     }
     return IntPtr.Zero;
  }
```